# Select2 AJAX doesn't update when changed programatically

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a Select2 that fetches its data remotely, but I would also like to set its value programatically. When trying to change it programatically, it updates the value of the `select`, and Select2 notices the change, but it doesn't update its label.

https://jsfiddle.net/Glutnix/ut6xLnuq/

```
$('#set-email-manually').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // THIS DOESN'T WORK PROPERLY!?

    $('#user-email-address') // Select2 select box
        .empty()
        .append('<option selected value="test@test.com">test@test.com</option>');
    $('#user-email-address').trigger('change');

});
```

I've tried a lot of different things, but I can't get it going. I suspect it might be a bug, so have [filed an issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4034) on the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kevin-Brown on GitHub replied](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4034#issuecomment-165907531) and said:

> The issue is that your templating methods are not falling back to text if email is not specified. The data objects being passed in should have the text of the <option> tag in the text property.

It turns out the result parameter to these two methods have more data in them than just the AJAX response!

```
templateResult: function(result) {
    console.log('templateResult', result);
    return result.email || result.text;
},
templateSelection: function(selection) {
    console.log('templateSelection', selection);
    return selection.email || selection.id;
},
```

Here's the fully functional [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Glutnix/7990vbtu/).

Comment: yes this will fix it. how ever if you want your placeholder to work as well you can remap the ajax result to the standard {id,text} format. check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

reading the docs I think maybe you are setting the options in the wrong way, you may use

```
data: {}
```

instead of

```
data, {}
```

and set the options included inside {}  separated by "," like this:

```
{
  option1: value1,
  option2: value2
}
```

so I have changed this part of your code:

```
$('#user-email-address').select2('data', {
  id: 'test@test.com',
  label: 'test@test.com'
});
```

to:

```
$('#user-email-address').select2({'data': {
    id: 'test@test.com',
    label: 'test@test.com'
  }
});
```

and the label is updating now.

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srajaee/ut6xLnuq/6/)

hope it helps.

Edit:

I correct myself, it seems like you can pass the data the way you were doing data,{}

the problem is with the data template..

reading the docs again it seems that the data template should be {id, text} while your ajax result is {id, email}, the set manual section does not work since it tries to return the email from an object of {id, text} with no email. so you either need to change your format selection function to return the text as well instead of email only or remap the ajax result.

I prefer remapping the ajax results and go the standard way since this will make your placeholder work as well which is not working at the moment because the placeholder template is {id,text} also it seems.

so I have changed this part of your code:

```
        processResults: function(data, params) {
            var payload = {
                results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                  return { id: item.email, text: item.email }; 
                })
            };
            return payload;
        }
```

and removed these since they are not needed anymore:

```
    templateResult: function(result) {
        return result.email;
    },
    templateSelection: function(selection) {
        return selection.email;
    }
```

updated fiddle: [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srajaee/ut6xLnuq/12/)

Comment: This works, but only by reinitialising Select2, and simultaneously removing the AJAX behaviour. I can no longer pick an email address. Though re-initialising might just be what I need to do. Will try this at work on Monday.

Comment: updated the answer to work with ajax too after setting manual

Comment: Note that your revised `templateResult` and `templateSelection` are actually not needed, they match the default implementations.

Answer (score 0):

For me, without AJAX worked like this:

```
var select = $('.user-email-address');
var option = $('<option></option>').
     attr('selected', true).
     text(event.target.value).
     val(event.target.id);
/* insert the option (which is already 'selected'!) into the select */
option.appendTo(select);
/* Let select2 do whatever it likes with this */
select.trigger('change');
```

Comment: Yes, I fully expect that to work without AJAX, but it's **_WITH_** AJAX that's my problem.